# Why don't /etc/group and /etc/password match?

Tags: users, group

OK this is a basic question showing my ignorance of sysadmin matters...

Looking at the UNIX system I work on, my /etc/passwd entry says

my_name:x:uid:gid:comments:home directory:login shell

Then when I go and look at group 'gid' in /etc/group, I see

group_name:x:gid:some_other_name

So how come /etc/passwd thinks I am a member of the group, but /etc/group doesn't? Am I a member of the group or aren't I?

Is this normal? Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` shows each user's *primary group*. `/etc/group` shows users who have a given group as one of their supplementary groups. For example, my username `dan` has the group `dan` as its primary group, so that is what appears in the group field in `/etc/passwd`. The user `dan` is also in the groups `wheel`, `mailadmin` and `svn`, so the entries for those groups in `/etc/group` list `dan` in the final field, which denotes group members.

Answer (score 5):

The usernames in `/etc/group` only contain users who are in the group as a supplementary group, not a primary group. Primary group information is stored in `/etc/passwd`. The initgroups(3) manpage was the only documentation I could find to indicate this:

```
NAME
       initgroups - initialize the supplementary group access list
FILES
       /etc/group          group database file
```

Comment: Fantastic - answers my question. Thanks @jordanm!